# How to get over error 40 "Access Denied -- You do not have access" in SugarCRM?

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

Here are the request params (url = http://sugarcrm.localhost/service/v4_1/rest.php):

```
method=get_entry_list&input_type=json&response_type=json
&rest_data {"session":"2q67jvlce802e4htsqc94oshkat9henvicvfclprhrbd8ef6k0o0",
"module_name":"Contacts",
"query":"email1=ychaouche@feeder.fr",
"order_by":"",
"offset":0,
"select_fields":[],
"link_name_to_fields_array":[],
"max_results":0,
"deleted":false}
```

I get this as a result :

```
"{"name":"Access Denied","number":40,"description":"You do not have access"}"
```

**Edit**

This error is fired whenever the subquery is malformed, not necessarily when one doesn't have access to a module, so one should be aware of it.

Comment: The rest_data section should be all JSON and URL encoded. Other than that, are you sure you proper module access?

Comment: If I change the query from email1=ychaouche@feeder.fr to first_name=chaouche it works fine. I've read[this blog post](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/02/08/changes-to-web-services-api-in-sugarcrm-6-4-0/#disqus_thread) yesterday but didn't understand completely what people were saying in the comments. Is there some sort of limitation in the query parameter ? because changing that single parameter got me around the Access Denied error. And to answer your question : no, I don't know if I have proper module access, how can I check for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one solution to my problem is to replace that query with this one :

```
contacts.id 
IN 
(
   SELECT email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
   FROM   email_addr_bean_rel
   JOIN   email_addresses
   ON     email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id
   WHERE
   email_addresses.email_address = 'ychaouche@feeder.fr'
)
```

Since appearantly the email1 and email2 fields are not queriable (they're not in the Contacts table). The workaround consists of querying the email_address table via a subquery.

**EDIT** : so that the whole query should look something like this :

```
method=get_entry_list&input_type=json&response_type=json
&rest_data {"session":"2q67jvlce802e4htsqc94oshkat9henvicvfclprhrbd8ef6k0o0",
"module_name":"Contacts",
"query":
"
contacts.id 
IN 
(
   SELECT email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
   FROM   email_addr_bean_rel
   JOIN   email_addresses
   ON     email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id
   WHERE
   email_addresses.email_address = 'ychaouche@feeder.fr'
)  
"
"order_by":"",
"offset":0,
"select_fields":[],
"link_name_to_fields_array":[],
"max_results":0,
"deleted":false}
```

Comment: Could you please explain where this should go in trhe API call? Is this what "query" should become or do you call this query with different API endpoint?

Comment: @grzegorzjanik I edited the answer to show where. As I said in the answer, it should go in the query parameter, as a replacement to `email1=ychaouche@feeder.fr`