# How Do I Prevent Duplicates When Adding Leads to SuiteCRM?

Tags: php, json, rest, crm, suitecrm

The [developer guide for SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/wiki/index.php/Developer_Guide) is kind of incomplete (at least here in Q4 2017) compared to the [old SugarCRM one](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Method_Calls/) that it was based on before the [software fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuiteCRM). So, by downloading the [WordPress Plugin for SugarCRM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-widget-sugarcrm-lead-module/), I was able to figure out the REST API and JSON for adding a sales lead into SuiteCRM with the following code.

Now how do I prevent duplicates by home phone, mobile phone, or email address?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

CRM::loginCRM('admin','xxxxPASSWORDxxxxxx');

$aResult = CRM::addLead(array(
  'name' => 'John Doe',
  'description' => 'sample description',
  'salutation' => 'Mr.',
  'first_name' => 'John',
  'last_name' => 'Doe',
  'do_not_call' => 'No',
  'phone_home' => '202-111-2222',
  'phone_mobile' => '202-111-2222',
  'email1' => 'test@example.com',
  'primary_address_street' => '123 Main Street',
  'primary_address_street2' => '',
  'primary_address_street3' => '',
  'primary_address_city' => 'New York',
  'primary_address_state' => 'NY'
));

print_r($aResult);
CRM::logoutCRM();


die('OK');
/////////////////////////

class CRM {

private static $SessionID = '';

private static $URL = 'https://mycrmserver-example.com/service/v4_1/rest.php';

private static $User = '';
private static $Shadow = '';

public static function sendJSON($a) {
  $s = file_get_contents(
    self::$URL,
    false,
    stream_context_create(
      array(
        'http' => array (
          'method' => 'POST',
          'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => http_build_query($a)
        )
      )
    )
  );
  $a2 = json_decode($s);
  return $a2;
}

public static function loginCRM($sUser,$sPass) {
  $sShadow = md5($sPass);
  self::$User = $sUser;
  self::$Shadow = $sShadow;
  $asLogin = array (
    'method' => 'login',
    'input_type' => 'JSON',
    'response_type' => 'JSON',
    'rest_data' => json_encode(array(
      'user_auth' => array(
        'user_name' => $sUser,
        'password' => $sShadow,
        'version' => 1
      ),
      'application_name' => 'RestTest',
      'name_value_list' => array()
    ))
  );
  $a = self::sendJSON($asLogin);
  self::$SessionID = $a->id;
}

public static function logoutCRM() {
  $asLogin = array (
    'method' => 'logout',
    'input_type' => 'JSON',
    'response_type' => 'JSON',
    'rest_data' => json_encode(array(
      'user_auth' => array(
        'user_name' => self::$User,
        'password' => self::$Shadow,
        'version' => 1
      ),
      'application_name' => 'RestTest',
      'name_value_list' => array()
    ))
  );
  self::sendJSON($asLogin);
}

public static function addLead($a) {
  $asNameValueList = array();
  foreach($a as $sKey => $sVal) {
    $asNameValueList[] = array('name'=>$sKey,'value'=>$sVal);
  }
  $asAddEntry = array (
    'method' => 'set_entry',
    'input_type' => 'JSON',
    'response_type' => 'JSON',
    'rest_data' => json_encode(array(
      'session' => self::$SessionID,
      'module_name' => 'Leads',
      'name_value_list' => $asNameValueList
    ))
  );
  $a = self::sendJSON($asAddEntry);
  return $a;
}

} // end CRM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these functions into your CRM class and check them before adding a lead. I had a little help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13476070/105539) that incidentally gave me some insights. Also, I recommend you do things to tighten down your security such as add an .htaccess or NGINX rule that only allows certain IP addresses or require certain headers to reach anything in your /service folder, and /service/* subfolders either over HTTP or HTTPS.

```php
public static function leadExistsByPhone($sHomePhone,$sMobilePhone) {
  $sHomePhone = (empty($sHomePhone)) ? 'xxxxxinvalid' : $sHomePhone;
  $sMobilePhone = (empty($sMobilePhone)) ? 'xxxxxinvalid' : $sMobilePhone;
  $asCheck = array (
    'method' => 'get_entry_list',
    'input_type' => 'JSON',
    'response_type' => 'JSON',
    'rest_data' => json_encode(array(
      'session' => self::$SessionID,
      'module_name' => 'Leads',
      'query' => "
        leads.phone_home = '$sHomePhone'
        OR leads.phone_mobile = '$sMobilePhone'
      ",
      'order_by' => 'leads.date_entered DESC',
      'offset' => '0',
      'select_fields' => array(),
      'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(),
      'max_results' => 999999,
      'deleted' => false
    ))
  );
  $a = self::sendJSON($asCheck);
  $nCount = @ $a->result_count;
  $nCount = intval($nCount);
  return ($nCount > 0);
}

public static function leadExistsByEmail($sEmail) {
  if (!filter_var($sEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die('DENIED: invalid email address format');
  }
  $asCheck = array (
    'method' => 'get_entry_list',
    'input_type' => 'JSON',
    'response_type' => 'JSON',
    'rest_data' => json_encode(array(
      'session' => self::$SessionID,
      'module_name' => 'Leads',
      'query' => "
        leads.id IN
        (
          SELECT email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
          FROM   email_addr_bean_rel
          JOIN   email_addresses
          ON     email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id
          WHERE
          email_addresses.email_address = '$sEmail'
        )
      ",
      'order_by' => 'leads.date_entered DESC',
      'offset' => '0',
      'select_fields' => array(),
      'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(),
      'max_results' => 999999,
      'deleted' => false
    ))
  );
  $a = self::sendJSON($asCheck);
  $nCount = @ $a->result_count;
  $nCount = intval($nCount);
  return ($nCount > 0);
}
```

Comment: And if you want to update that existing lead, just modify the `leadExists*()` functions a little so that you get the ID and then pass the `id` in the `$asNameValueList` array with the `set_entry` method.